# Считать jpg по 8 бит, по 16 бит, по 24 бита

Tags: python

Имеется jpg файл. Хочу получить список битовых цепочек файла по 8, по 16 и по 24 бита, используя python. В дальнейшем хочу проанализировать распределение вероятности появления каждого из исходов для данных трех размерностей.

На данный момент разобрался, как получить список из десятичных чисел по 8 бит:

```
with open("1.jpg", "rb") as imageFile:

f = imageFile.read()
b = list(bytearray(f))
```

Каким образом можно сделать то же самое для цепочек из 16 и 24 бит?

Comment: Можно в цикле читать по 2/3 байта и добавлять в list вручную.

Comment: `b = list(f)` делает то-же самое, как `b = list(bytearray(f))`, так как `f` уже есть bytearray.

Answer (score 2):

Так как вы уже начитали ваш файл до битовой цепочки `f`, вы можете её использовать как псевдо-файл и читать по 2 (или по 3) байта из неё в цикле:

```
import io

f_as_file = io.BytesIO(f)

c = []
while True:
    part = f_as_file.read(2)         # или 3
    if part:
        c.append(part)
    else:
        break
```

или с применением *абстракции списка (list comprehension)* (вместо инициализации списка `c` и добавления к нему в цикле):

```
import io

BYTES = 2                            # или 3

f_as_file = io.BytesIO(f)
c = [f_as_file.read(BYTES) for __ in range(len(f) // BYTES)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы уже начитали ваш файл до битовой цепочки `f`, вы можете из её сделать *2- или 3-байтовые отрезки:*

```
BYTES_COUNT = 2           # или 3, или даже 1 - вместо вашего b = list(bytearray(f))

c = [f[i:i+BYTES_COUNT] for i in range(0, len(f), BYTES_COUNT)]
```

---

**Тест:** Пусть `f = b'\0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\x08\x09\x0A\x0B'`.

Тогда для `BYTES_COUNT = 2` будет вывод команды `print(c)` такой:

> ```
> [b'\x00\x01', b'\x02\x03', b'\x04\x05', b'\x06\x07', b'\x08\t', b'\n\x0b']
> ```

и для `BYTES_COUNT = 3` такой:

> ```
> [b'\x00\x01\x02', b'\x03\x04\x05', b'\x06\x07\x08', b'\t\n\x0b']
> ```

*Примечание:*

`b'x09'` то-же самое как  `b'\t'` (табулятор) и `b'x0a'` то-же самое как  `b'\n'` (новая строка).